# Got different result using pycurl and request - any idea where is my mistake with pycurl?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, pycurl

i write code using pycurl and requests librairie,
the aim is to query a REST API, 
the results with "requests" is ok, 
but not with "pycurl", 
both share the same input data, but it seems something goes wrong with pycurl like the api do not get the body data.

can you help me to find my mistake in the pycurl code ?

```
requests_test.py: 

import requests 

data = {"account": {"email": "xxx@zzz.com"}} 
response = requests.post('https://myapi/api/v1/admin/create', json=data) 
print response.content

> python requests_test.py
{"error":"Admin already existing"}
```

and

```
pycurl_test.py

import pycurl, json

c = pycurl.Curl() 
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://myapi/api/v1/admin/create')
data = json.dumps({"account": {"email": "xxx@zzz.com"}})
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
c.perform()
c.close()
print data

> python pycurl_test.py
{"error":"account is missing, account[email] is missing}
```

i am sure it's something so big and stupid,that i do not see.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution,
in pycurl, you have to add this :

```
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json'])
```